# Visual Studio: Identifider "MSFDTEDIT_CLASS" is undefined

Tags: c, api, winapi, hyperlink, linker

I'm new to Visual Studio. I want to do Win32 programming in C and I need to have rich text edit there. I've tried to link msftedit.dll, but it doesn't seem to do it.
I have this:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"msftedit.dll")
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Also I tried to have `"msftedit.lib"` in project 
properties > linker > input > additional dependencies, but it gave me an error.

Comment: Have your checked your #includes?

Comment: @ShaunRamsey So I had to include comctl and richedit. Msftedit has to be include with LoadLibrary(), or so I think for now. Well it seems I get it running as of now, VS doesn't give me any errors, guess this is solved. edit: idk how to mark question as solved..

Comment: You mis-spelled "MSFTEDIT_CLASS" or forgot to include RichEdit.h.  There is nothing to link, you have to use LoadLibrary(L"msftedit.dll") in your code before the CreateWindowEx() call can work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include the proper header file. In this case, include *RichEdit.h*. In addition, use [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) to dynamically load the module that implements the control (*msftedit.dll*). If you don't, the call to `CreateWindowEx` will fail.